# JQueryUI Drag and Drop tutorial breaking in IE9 and IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I'm looking through a JQuery Drag and Drop tutorial here: http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/

It's a great tutorial, but I'm having some issues with the final project in Internet Explorer.  I'm using IE 9 and its developer tools to change the document mode from IE9, to IE8 and IE7.

If I change the document mode to IE9 standards, than none of the javascript created card div elements appear.  If I change the document mode to IE7, than the number text inside the draggable cards is cut in half.  IE8 mode seems to work - of course, the rounded edges do not though.

Here's a link to the finished product if you want to test yourself:  http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html

I've tried using Blueprint's IE style sheet, but no help there.  Also I've changed the JQuery and JQueryUI versions to these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Still no change.

Anyone know what could be causing these issues?

Answer (score 0):

try removing the following line and see if it works. I had a similar situation and it solved the problem. Obviously, you will need to rewrite the code to get the functionality.

`stack: '#cardPile div'`,